# Building Island in Pacific Ocean by pouring continuous lava

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, technology

I'm thinking to build an island by pouring lava into the ocean, with the advanced technology, around 40 years later,
by making a special pipe connected to the ground (maybe near volcano/es)
since the lava can cool off fast, there should be also a special heater inside the pipe,
simultaneously cold outside so the pipe and the heater temperature are stable and won't melt.

But the question are the consequences:

- Losing something beneath the ground will increase earthquakes since it needs to be adjusted
- Multiple Pipes are connected, It'll cause more thermal heat
- Since it is located at Pacific Ocean, it will be much easier to form a Cyclone/Typhoon
- (Maybe) some nearby fishes will die.

This is what I know so far, but will it harm the Earth so greatly that it might wipe most of humans?

**EDIT:** I just found out. My greatest enemy here is it will affect the sea level drastically.

Comment: This is similar to how real islands are forming. Are you going deposit the lava near the volcano, or move it 100s or 1000s of kilometers away?

Comment: I know this sounds weird, but 'do harm to the Earth' isn't a specific criteria. You'll be creating land where there once was water - is that harm? You'll wreck the nearby aquatic environment, which could also be viewed as harm. And if you're asking for all the consequences for dumping lava into water, that might be too broad of a question.

Comment: I'm transporting the lava from near volcanoes (Japan's Volcanoes, Philippine's Volcanoes,Autstalia's) to the Pacific ocean. So yes, around 1000 kilometers away

Comment: @Halfthawed I made some edit in my question

Comment: You have a pipe running directly to magma?  How do you turn it off?  Any valve will eventually fail under such heat

Comment: Been done.  Hawai'i, Oahu, Kauai, Maui, and many others.

Answer (score 4):

**No major consequences**

The Pacific Ocean is gargantuan and cold. Like most oceans, once you dip a few dozen feet beneath the surface, it starts getting pretty cold, around 17 Celsius or 63 Fahrenheit. Dumping a bunch of lava in the ocean isn't going to affect it at all. Dumping incredibly large amounts of lava into the Pacific Ocean isn't going to affect it at all. How do I know this? Well, because there are an estimated [1,000,000+ underwater volcanoes](http://volcano.oregonstate.edu/submarine) in the Pacific already. Granted, most of them aren't the classic image of the volcano, but the Pacific Ocean already has all that lava being dumped in it already. A little more lava to make a single island isn't a big deal.

Now, what you do want to worry about is the steam you'll let off by application of lava to water. Since you're adding it from the top, the lava will cause a steam explosion on the surface (as opposed to releasing that steam underwater where it can cool on it's way to the surface, although volcanoes have been known to release bubbles large enough to [swallow ships whole](https://www.forbes.com/sites/davidbressan/2019/10/18/volcano-forms-giant-bubbles-large-enough-to-swallow-an-entire-ship/#21fb33f22b8d)). Anyway, back on topic, you'll be releasing a lot of steam into the air, which thanks to the butterfly effect, will have a one-time effect on the weather system. I don't know what that effect will be, thanks to the butterfly effect, but the good news is that this will only happen during the construction of the island. No to mention that there are active volcanoes near the surface of the Pacific which also regularly send up plumes of steam. You will *affect* the weather, but not grossly change it.

The island itself will not threaten the seabed it's on. Lava will pool up on itself naturally so it won't have stability issues, and the Earth's crusts already handles continents, another small island in the pacific isn't a problem. Particularly since lava, once cooled, generally forms a rock called pumice which weighs *less* than water does, so your island is actually lighter. You might scare some nearby fish / flash boil them, but as long as you pick an abandoned stretch of sea (and not a coral reef), you won't kill anything that you wouldn't fish up and eat anyway. (Subject to your personal tastes on seafood, naturally.)

It will not poses a threat to humans as a whole, or the world as a whole. Probably. There's one circumstance I can think of which it would, and that's you didn't specify the size of your island. Now, technically, Greenland is an island, albeit a massive one. And, even though I've been saying that the heat introduction into the ocean is meaningless, it's not meaningless if you introduce a lava mass the size of *Greenland*.  So if you wanted to cause trouble and you decided to make an island the size of Greenland, it's possible that you could inadvertently trigger the conditions for a [hypercane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercane). Which, to put it briefly, is a hurricane, except it's apocalyptic conditions within the hurricane, which isn't threatening to *all* life on Earth, but it's a natural disaster that we aren't prepared for. (Unless the hypercane rips holes clean through the ozone layer, which it can do being that it extends to the upper stratosphere, at which point it *will* be threatening for life on Earth. But that only a faint possibility if you use an island the size of Greenland.)

If you're looking for advice on how to build such an island, I'd recommend following the same basic way that underwater volcanos form such islands - layer by layer.